# how to make watchkit extension app and my iphone app share the same icloud databases

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, watchkit, cloudkit

Im trying to make my app for the apple watch but I am running into a problem with the cloud containers. When I created cloud kit for the watch extension it created its own container/database so now Im trying to get them both to share the same one. Ive tried to specify the custom container I want but it is not working. Please Help!
[image]

Comment: Make sure that instead of CKContainer.defaultContainer() you use: CKContainer(identifier: "iCloud.com.Moodler.Moodler")

Comment: Ah, that was the problem? I will put it in an answer then :)

Answer (score 6):

Since your watch app will use a specific CloudKit container you have to initiate your container using the identifier. You can not use the defaultContainer.

So you have to make sure that instead of CKContainer.defaultContainer() you use: CKContainer(identifier: "iCloud.com.Moodler.Moodler")

The rest of your code will remain the same.

Answer (score 2):

Apple has provided a sample app for iCloud data sharing across all targets. Search for ‘lister watchkit’. They mentioned setup procedure in detailed document - ‘iOS and Watch Quick Start’

Common bundle identifier prefix is shared across all targets e.g., com.example.myApp. This prefix can be used to create a iCloud Document identifier.