# CloudKit error using watchOS 3

Tags: ios, swift, ios-simulator, watchkit, cloudkit

I believe I have everything set up right, and everything works for `CloudKit` in the iOS Simulator, but I **can't get `CloudKit` to work in the Watch Simulator: "Couldn't send a valid signature"**

Does anyone know why this would be?

- I know `CloudKit` works in watchOS 3 per Apple "iCloud interactions.
  Starting with watchOS 3, the `WatchKit` extension can communicate
  directly with `CloudKit` and other iCloud technologies."
- I already did Settings > iCloud and then log in using your Apple ID
  on the iOS simulator per [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29886616/couldnt-send-a-valid-signature-error-when-using-cloudkit)
- In the Watch Extension, I'm calling CloudKit using `CKContainer(identifier:"iCloud.com.xx.xx")` per [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30458459/how-to-make-watchkit-extension-app-and-my-iphone-app-share-the-same-icloud-datab)
- I double-checked Apple's doc to make sure I didn't miss something:
  [enter link description here](https://github.com/leecade/appleSample/blob/master/ListerforAppleWatchiOSandOSX/iOS%20and%20Watch%20Quick%20Start.pdf)
- I'm accessing the same `CloudKit` container on the Watch that I am on
  iOS, so nothing is wrong with accessibility to the data in `CloudKit`
- The CloudKit capability with the container identifier is set
  correctly in the Watch Target

Comment: Is the CloudKit capability with the container identifier set in the watch target?

Comment: @Jerry yup the CloudKit capability with the container identifier is set correctly in the watch target.  Thanks for checking on that, I'll add it to my question information too.  Let me know if you can think of anything else.

Comment: Does it work on hardware, but not the simulator?

Comment: @Jerry yeah it works on hardware but not Apple Watch Simulator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[According to Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/RN-watchOSSDK-3.1/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40017563-CH1-DontLinkElementID_15):

> CloudKit usage is blocked on watchOS Simulators. Running any test will
>   throw a “Not Authenticated” error even though you are signed in via
>   the paired iOS Simulator. Workaround: Use CloudKit on paired devices
>   with watchOS 3 and iOS 10.

This is from the watchOS 3 release notes, but does not seem to be fixed yet. Just test on a real watch and everything will work fine.